# How to setup MS SQL for Lightswitch intrinsic deploy - exception occurred when building the database for the application

Tags: sql, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

Question
Sign in to vote
0
Sign in to vote
VS2013 Community html project, SQL2014 Standard db

Does anyone have a good walkthrough of deploying with an intrinsic db?  Deployment with external db works fine, but not with intrinsic.

F5 build works fine on localhost with external or intrinsic db, server deploy to IIS/SQL works fine with external db... just not with intrinsic db...

None of the docs I have found are real detailed about how to setup sql server to handle the intrinsic deployment.

Created the sql project, selected that in LS app properties.  Do I create a DB on the SQL server or does LS do that?  The Publish dialog on the database step says the admin account will be used to "create and update" the db.  Have tried sql admin account with and without specifying a target db.  Can the user account be the same as the admin account?  Tried that both ways.

Comment: How are you deploying - using Web Deploy or publishing to a package?

Comment: Web deploy, thanks

       at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ServerGenerated.Implementation.DataServiceImplementation`1.get_ObjectContext()
  InnerException: System.ArgumentException
       HResult=-2147024809
       Message=Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.
       Source=System.Data

Comment: I normally publish to a package but I'll try to help. The messsage about "create and update" is underneath an entry field which is expecting a DB connection string (the full message is "This connection will be used to create and update ..."). It sounds like you might only be putting login details in there. Can you share (suitably sanitised of course) the connection string you're entering?

Comment: The publish database schema connection is Data Source=server,1433;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=username;Password=password and this sql login has dbowner role on the sql server and passes the "test connection" in the publish dialog.  Again, this all works fine with external db, just not with intrinsic.  So seems like the issue is somewhere between the SQL database project (or not) and the admin/user connections.

Comment: Moved from RDS to a fully managed SQL instance and now works.

Answer (score 0):

Moved from RDS to a fully managed SQL instance and now works. –  user5050939 just now   edit   delete